# Movie maker avi is stretched

Tags: godot-4

In Godot 4.1 I've made an avi with Movie maker Mode. Only instead of being 224 x 256 pixels the avi is stretched to 224 x 512.

Compare screenshot to movie

[image: Window display]

[image: screenshot]

[image: Movie played in VLC]

I don't want to fix this post-event in ffmpeg.
What's going wrong and can it be fixed?